# Appropriate way to handle deprecated `adminmedia` templatetag and {% admin_media_prefix %}

Tags: django, django-1.5

From django 1.5 onwards, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/releases/1.5/#miscellaneous

> The template tags library adminmedia, which only contained the
>   deprecated template tag {% admin_media_prefix %}, was removed.
>   Attempting to load it with {% load adminmedia %} will fail. If your
>   templates still contain that line you must remove it.

So what is the appropriate way to **replace code** found in legacy libraries and my legacy projects which still uses `{% load adminmedia %}` and loads css like:-

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% load adminmedia %}{% admin_media_prefix %}css/login.css">
```

?

Answer (score 24):

Since Django 1.3 you can use [django.contrib.staticfiles](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/) app.

Make sure that django.contrib.staticfiles is included in your INSTALLED_APPS and the STATIC_ROOT and STATIC_URL options are specified in your settings.py.

Then run `manage.py collectstatic` command and all applications' static files will be collected in STATIC_ROOT folder.

In the templates you can use the `{{ STATIC_URL }}` context variable (make sure that django.core.context_processors.static is included in TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS) or the `{% static %}` template tag.

```
<link href="{{ STATIC_URL }}admin/css/login.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

or

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<link href="{% static 'admin/css/login.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: I am looking about the docs for STATIC_PATH and can't see anything, should that be STATIC_ROOT?

Comment: @wobbily_col You're right about STATIC_ROOT, I've submitted an edit for this answer (awaiting peer review).

Comment: Is pulling those files into your own project really the recommended solution? It sounds like a hack.

Answer (score 5):

I just copied what's in `base.css`:

```
{% load admin_static %}
```

and then

```
<link href="{% static 'admin/css/base.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
```

(replace `base.css` with whatever you need, like `login.css` in your case)

Make sure you have `django.contrib.staticfiles` in your `INSTALLED_APPS`.

(I didn't need to configure `STATIC_ROOT` and run `manage.py collectstatic` as suggested previously by Anton)